# How to fit a linear model?

Tags: r

I would like to create a function like this:

In R it is possible to use this as a general example I found this:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=mydata)
```

and my data are:

```
Ay Ty year
20 11 2009
48 27 2010
35 58 2011
```

How is it possible to make it for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you want to fit a linear model. This is done with the `lm` function. Usually you have more data rows then coefficients to fit, but it will work:

```
> d <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="Ay Ty year
+ 20 11 2009
+ 48 27 2010
+ 35 58 2011")
> d 
  Ay Ty year
1 20 11 2009
2 48 27 2010
3 35 58 2011
> model <- lm(Ay ~ Ty + year, data = d)
> summary(model)

Call:
lm(formula = Ay ~ Ty + year, data = d)

Residuals:
ALL 3 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -1.441e+05         NA      NA       NA
Ty          -2.733e+00         NA      NA       NA
year         7.173e+01         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 2 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

This leaves you with

```
Ay = -144100 - 2.733 * Ty + 71.73 * year + error
```

as a result with minimum squared residuals.